# How can I include a penalty to my (linear) model?

Tags: linear-programming, modeling, penalty-based-optimization

Is it possible in a linear model to include a penalty if both variables $x$ and $y$ are greater than zero? I would like to have no penalty, if $x$ OR $y$ is zero.

For example, I have a model:

$$
\begin{align}
&\min_{x,y} c x + dy \\
\text{s.t.}& \\
& ax \le b \\
& zy \le e \\
& x,y \ge 0
\end{align}
$$

Comment: I suspect you want to enforce $$x\cdot y = 0$$ This is a **complementarity constraint**. No pure LP formulations for this.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot do this within a linear program. If the penalty is a fixed amount (not proportional to the size of $X$ or $Y$), and assuming you can infer upper bounds $M_X$ and $M_Y$ on $X$ and $Y,$ you can do it by introducing binary variables $W_X,$ $W_Y$ and $Z.$ In the objective function, add the product of $Z$ and the penalty value you want. New constraints are $$X \le M_X \cdot W_X,$$ $$Y \le M_Y \cdot W_Y$$and$$Z\ge W_X + W_Y - 1.$$

Comment: +1.  You can optionally relax $Z$ to be nonnegative instead of binary.

Comment: Indeed ... although I'm never sure whether a solver will be faster with or without the integrality restriction.

Comment: And the solver might automatically detect and restore the integrality restriction that the user explicitly relaxed. :)

Comment: Proving once again that the solver is smarter than I am. :-(

Answer (score 1):

Obj: $min \ cx + dy + w\epsilon$
3 additional constraints
$y >= w$
$x >= w$
$w >= {{x+y}\over M} - 1$ where we is binary and M could be chosen such that $1 < {{x+y}\over M} <= 2$. My estimate M should be in this range $[\lvert{b\over a}-{e\over z}\rvert,\max({b\over a}, {e\over z})]$

Comment: Are you assuming that $x$ and $y$ are integer variables? This was not stated in the original question.